# How to get two h4 tags on the same line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to get 2 `<h4>` tags to be on the same row in bootstrap however I can't get it to work.

I'd like to have one `<h4>` aligned with the left side, and one with the right side.

I've tried floating left and floating right but to no avail.

http://jsfiddle.net/v8ufbbdL/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="coolContainer">
        <h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1>
        <h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.coolContainer {
    border: 3px solid #bbb;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
.coolContainer h1:first-of-type {
    float: left;
}

.coolContainer h1:last-of-type {
    float: right;
}
```

This works.  Just floats the first one left and the second one right.  http://jsfiddle.net/x8eszw59/

**EDIT**

Er, I guess you'd have to change this to "h4" instead of "h1", but you get the idea.  I was just going off the "h1"'s you have in your code.

**ALSO**

It seems like you are missing your column div's inside of your row.  For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

If you wanted to only use Bootstrap, just make 2 columns of 6, and put one header tag in one and the other in the second.

http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: The part after `ALSO` solved the issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to convert them from `block`s to `inline`s.:

```
h1 {display:inline;}
```

However, this might break if they overflow on to the next line. To make sure they stay put you can make them css `table-cell`s:

```
h1 {display:table-cell;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#v {
float:left;
    border: 6px solid #bbb;
}
#vk
{
float:right;
border: 6px solid #bbb;
}

</style>  


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="v"><h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1></div>
        <div id="vk"><h1>Bootstrap jsFiddle Skeleton</h1></div>

    </div>
</div>
```